# A solution of second order differential equation has finite zeros or infinite zeros

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the solution of $y'' + p(x)y' +q(x)y = 0$ on every interal $[a,b]$ has either finite number of zeros or is identically zero.

I'm completely lost here. I've tried using wronskian and Liouville's theroem but they gave me nothing. I have no idea where does the distinction between finite and infinite zeros come from. What conditions are there for solutions to have different zero sets.

I've tried computing the derivative of $y(t_0)$ while assuming that $y(t_0) = 0$. I got $y'(t_0) = lim_{t\to t_0} \frac{y(t)}{t-t_0}$ and from the uniqueness and existence theroem I can show that $y(t) \equiv 0$ if $y'(t_0) = 0$. There are no assumptions on $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.

Comment: Check Sturm's separation theorem. It states that the zeros of any solution are isolated (it is normally stated with $p = 0$, which can be accomplished with a variable change). If there was an infinite number of zeros in $[a,b]$, the set formed by those zeros would have a limit point $t_0 \in [a,b]$, which would not be isolated.

Comment: Hmm I dont think our lecturer expects us to know that theroem. We haven't covered isolated points and such yet

Comment: the proof of Sturm's separation theorem (the first part, at least) is a simple exercise that you can mimic in your solution. The point is that you have a non isolated zero you are able to construct a BVP with zero solution.

Comment: My initial comment is unprecise... I should have said "the zeros of any non-identically zero solution".